# Where should I put a modified version of l() function?

Tags: 7

I want to customize [`l()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) function, which is part of Drupal 7 core and it is located in the common.inc file.

Where should I put such a function?

Modifying `l()` function or putting a new function in the `common.inc` would be considered hacking the core.

Comment: What is it particular that you want to change? There might be a better place to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put it in your custom module. I think it's anyway good development practice to have a custom module in every project you develop.

What I do usually, is that I create `MY_MODULE.helpers.inc` file, and include it at the top of the `.module` file.

Here's an example of `.module` file:

```
// Get helper functions.
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/MY_MODULE.helpers.inc';
```

This way, if your module is enabled, the function will become available to other modules or your theme, and your `.module` file is cleaner because it doesn't include the helper functions.

You can see my [Drupal 7 Boilerplate](https://github.com/aramboyajyan/drupal7-boilerplate) and specifically the [`boilerplate.helpers.inc`](https://github.com/aramboyajyan/drupal7-boilerplate/blob/master/boilerplate.helpers.inc) file on Github.

Comment: This wouldn't allow one to use the function named `l();` as it has already been defined right? So you'd need to rename the function to `my_l();`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I don't think you can really override the core `l()` function.